# How to save mediaplayer instance on going to another fragment from current and again regaining it while returning back from that fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to stop media player to what it is and go on that fragment guided by button in below and again while returning i want to get same paused media player[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AsTS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by following below approach

1) Create Media Player instance on Activity rather on Fragment
By this on whatever fragment you are you can get Media Player instance at any time without worrying the actual fragment

```
I want to stop media player to what it is and go on that fragment guided by button in below
```

2) On clicking stop button(as you mentioned, I am expecting this button on any fragment) get the instance of Media Player and call Media Player stop method.

```
and again while returning i want to get same paused media player
```

3) When you get back the same fragment, you will already have the same instance of Media Player. And then you can do you desire operation

I hope that helps you

Comment: i want to work on fragment only.... its my requirement of current project i am handling. And I m not bit clear sir.. can you elaborate...

Comment: it does not matter you are working on fragment or it is requirement. Some how you must be using Activity that is holding those fragment. I am talking about that activity. Use that activity to create Media Player instance and use this instance in fragment freely.